# Battery charging circuit with fuel gauge monitoring. Always measuring a discharging current

Tags: battery-charging, charging, fuel-gauge

I have designed and produced this simple schematic of a circuit that's supposed to charge a LiPo battery from a 5V source through the MCP73831 controller while measuring the SoC with a MAX17260 fuel gauge monitor. The problem that I'm seeing is that the MAX17260 is always measuring a positive current (like the battery is always being discharged).

Vbat - positive terminal of LiPo cell.

VCC_1 - system power.

[image]
[image: MAX17260]

[MAX17263 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17263.pdf)
[MCP73831 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf)

Comment: Where is your battery connected. I can't see it in your diagrams. What numbers are the MAX chip giving you and what load do you have.

Comment: Battery is connected to 'Vbat' net, as mentioned in the post. Thanks!
MAX is saying current 9mA both with the charger plugged in and when removed. It's also consistent with the expected load.

Comment: So, if your loading is 9 mA and the MAX chip is reporting 9 mA, what is the problem here? Personally speaking I think you need to show where the battery is connected in your circuit and also show where the load is. I would also say that your battery should be connected to pin 3 of the MCP73831 and not where you appear to be saying it is connected.

Comment: I've used this chip before. When the battery is charging, it should report a negative value (current flowing into the battery). So it reporting 9mA suggests it's only seeing the system current draw and not what actually happens to the cell.

If I connect it to pin 3, then the current sense resistor of the MAX17260  would become useless as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe your charger is not working then.

Comment: @Andyaka : I doubt that's the case as the voltage to the cell increases when the charger is connected.